# How to encode a RGB Image to an n_class One Hot Tensor in PyTorch

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, torch, torchvision

So, I am working on a segmentation task and what I need to do is convert an RGB image to an n channel one hot matrix to be used as labels for a U-Net Model

What I have done is calculating the colors in the images. The number or colors are equivalent to the number of classes.

What I try do do in the PerPixelClassMatrix function is iterate through the Image and make a matrix of n dimensions of 0s and 1s since I have the color and class for each pixel.

```
import glob
from tqdm import tqdm
import numpy as np


class HotEncoder():
    def __init__(self, dir, extension, is_binary=True):
        self.dir = dir
        self.extension = extension
        self.is_binary = is_binary
        if is_binary:
            self.color = {(0, 0, 0): 1, (255, 255, 255): 2}
        else:
            self.color = dict()

    def gen_colors(self):
        """Iterates through the entire dataset and finds the total colours
            in the images so that they can be used to one hot the image matrix
            for the training data"""
        if self.is_binary:
            return self.color
        else:
            n_color=1
            images = glob.glob(self.dir + '/*.' + self.extension)
            for img in tqdm(images, desc="Generating Color Pallte to Hot Encode"):
                image = skimage.io.imread(img)
                shape_ = image.shape
                for x in range(shape_[0]):
                    for y in range(shape_[1]):
                        clr= tuple(image[x][y][:])
                        if clr not in self.color.keys():
                            self.color.update({n_color: clr})
                            n_color+=1
                        else:
                            pass
        return self.color

    def PerPixelClassMatrix(self, Image):
        """Takes an Image and returns a per pixel class
            identification map"""
        class_list= []
        class_mat= np.array([])
        shape_= Image.shape
        for x in range(shape_[0]):
            for y in range(shape_[1]):
                clr= tuple(Image[x][y][:])
                if clr in self.color.keys():
                    class_list.append(self.color[clr])
                else:
                    pass
        return class_list
```

I dont want to run an entire loop for generating a one hot image of n channel. Is there an easy way to construct such a matrix which the colors known.

Comment: Do you want to transform output/labels so it fits with the loss? If so there is a much easier way to do it.

Comment: Yes, Could you tell better ways to do so ? ^u^

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate image segmentation loss, you could do:

```
output = model(input)  # raw logit output in shape [1, 3, 512, 512]
loss = criterion(F.log_softmax(output,1), target)  # target in shape [1, 512, 512]
```

Target would contain labels `[0, N)` with your mask indices. I assume your input image is 3 channel RGB.

[Source of the answer](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/loss-function-for-segmentation-models/32129), example could be found over there if needed.